# C# reference type - string and object

Tags: c#

I am studying reference and value types in C#. According to documentation string and object are reference types. When we execute following code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 30;
        object o = a;
        AlterObject(o);

        Console.WriteLine(o);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void AlterSObject(object testO)
    {
        int b = 130;
        testO = b;
    }
```

It prints output as 30. Please explain if object is reference type, why value of object is not changed in function.

Comment: Because the function doesn't change anything on the object referenced by the `testO` variable.  It changes the variable to point to a new reference.  Had you done something like `testO.SomeProperty = "some value";` then that property would have changed on the referenced object.

Comment: I can´t see where you use a string. Ths 3 of the 4 duplicates don´t match the question, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass the value `30` as `object`, you create a new instance which *points* to 30 (this is called boxing), which you pass to the method.

This reference itself is passed - as **every** argument in .NET - by *value*. Thus you can´t change the **reference**, but only its fields or properties. You could re-reference any other object within your method, but because the parameter is still passed by value this won´t be reflected in the calling code.

But even by using the `ref`-keyword `a` won´t change, because it has nothing to do with the boxed object:

```
static void AlterSObject(ref object testO)
{
    int b = 130;
    testO = b;
}
```

Now `o` (which is the boxed object and has nothing to do with `a`) would reflect whatever you assigned to `testO` within `AlterSObject`. However `a` will **not** reflect it. See [my fiddle for test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yA6td4).

Comment: If I create 2 objects like following - 
object o = 30;
object o2 = o;
o = 60;

Why o and o2 does not share a memory location ?

Comment: @AkshayP Because you don´t *modify* the underlying object (`30`) , but just reference **another one** (`60`). So `o2` still points to the exact same instance (`30`).

Answer (score 0):

You never declared AlterObject()'s parameters as references, so its passing by value. C# will use a pass-by-value approach unless you designate the given parameter as a reference using the ref keyword. You will also need to either overload(as I did in the following sample code) or rewrite your method to accept reference values.

```
public class test{
static void Main(string[] args){
    int a = 30;
    object o = a;

    AlterObject(ref o);

    System.Console.WriteLine(o);
    System.Console.Read();
}

static void AlterObject(object testO){
    int b = 130;
    testO = b;
}

static void AlterObject(ref object testO){
    int b = 130;
    testO = b;
}
}
```